# making non-uniform probability distribution in java

Tags: java, probability, non-uniform-distribution

i am having total no of elements(say 500) in a java class, which will generate a population of 3 diff type (type A,Type B and Type C) of objects with a probability of A=0.3,B=0.2,C=0.5. i am not able to find a nice and easy solution ,can any one help me with a sample code or some reference

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to create 500 objects, with each of them being A, B or C with a certain probability?

Comment: create 150 A, 100 B and 250 C then shuffle. You now have 500 random objects with the desired probability of occurence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each element, generate a random int r between 0 and 9.

```
If 0 <= r < 3 then Type A.
If 3 <= r < 5 then Type B.
If 5 <= r < 10 then Type C.
```